# No output from AOZ3103DI buck converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, output

I built the typical application in the [datasheet](http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/aoz3103di.pdf) but after powering up the circuit I got no output and the IC is getting hot with in seconds even it is only consuming 60 mA, I am running the circuit from lab power supply.

I have double checked every connection and I have changed the IC 3 times but nothing is happening

Here is my schematic:[image] All ceramic caps

EDIT
Adding the PCB
Red Is top blue is bottom
[image: TOP]
[image: Buttom]
[image]

I am not sure what is wrong exactly!

Comment: Please edit your question to include a close-up photo of the PCB you are using, to build your design.

Comment: What does "no output" mean?

Comment: Did you notice that two of the pins on the jack are connected together? I don't think that was intentional, was it? Also, D2 is backwards in the schematic. I mean, it is under reverse bias and will not turn on. Maybe that is why you think it is not working. Did you double-check the pinout on your IC? Maybe you misnumbered one of the pins, or mirrored the footprint or something.

Comment: In the layout, is the red layer the top layer or the bottom layer?

Comment: Can you explain why you added so much copper to the LX net? Especially on the blue layer? Also, the way you have routed GND is pretty strange. I would suggest you relayout the board with most of the bottom side as GND and all traces and fills on top. Re-read the part of the datasheet that talks about keeping high-current loop areas small. Trace the current through the circuit in the two states when LX is high and when LX is low. Those paths need to be minimized, including the GND return path. Not sure if layout is your problem or if there is some other problem. But layout is not good.

Comment: Not too sure about the reverse polarity circuit. What is the maximum Vin you are expecting? What is the minimum or normal Vin? I would think you would want to swap locations of R5 and D1. Did you check to make sure Q1 is fully on?

Comment: No output means it measures almost zero(no change after applying 12v for the Vin ), yes the led is reversed in the schematic, but I will fix this, I have tested it on the PCB and it is correctly placed(home made pcb) and for the IC I have double checked every bin for short and open circuit

Comment: This is the first try to make this PCB and I added too much copper for heat dissipation, according to the datasheet it is recommended to be generous in power dissipation method(page 10), for the ground, I have a short path which comes at the lower side of the bottom layer, the other ground trace is actually connecting the other non-high current components because as I mentioned I wanted to maximize the power dissipation

Comment: The reverse polarity circuit is tested and it is working perfectly fine, I have tested it outside the PCB and on the PCB without any problems. The expecting working range from 9 to 15 V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have redesigned the PCB and made the bottom layer GND and it is now working fine

Here is the new Design

[image: Comb]
[image: TOP]
[image: Bottom]